# Finding parameters to maximize expected utility of random variable

Tags: regression, optimization

I'm trying to analyze some data consisting of five randomized parameters and a utility function which indirectly depends on the parameters, by experimentation.  That is to say, the parameters of the experiment are chosen randomly, and successes and failures are counted up.  I want to find parameters for which the expected utility of successes and failures is highest.

From my days in calculus, I can see that an algorithm could consist of:

1. Regression to a (hopefully analytically tractable) surface
2. Finding a maximum
3. Finding the pre-image of my maximum (if I use any of the C libraries I've seen, which seem to focus on the maximum value, not its pre-image)

But I'm not sure about the "fiddly bits" like:

- The distribution of points (I don't have any data yet)
- Any substantive idea of the shape of the surface, though I am expecting diminishing marginal utility, so it should be non-linear and have a bump.
- Numerical stability

This seems like it should be straight-forward, in terms of applied decision theory.  So, is my plan sensible?  Any pointers to literature, algorithms, C or Haskell libraries?

Addition in response to comment:

I'm trying to find the "best" parameters in terms of student performance.  The 5-tuple represents:

1. $b$: The "base" waiting time before seeing a problem again.
2. $p_1$: A constant factor if the student says the problem was easy.
3. $p_2$: A constant factor if the student says it was hard.
4. $p_3$: A constant factor if the student says it was "normal".
5. $p_4$: A constant factor if the student got it wrong.

The waiting time for the next viewing is computed by multiplying all of the responses the student has issued, and the base waiting time, and computing $e^{b \prod p_{i,j}}$.  So, for example, a wrong answer makes the waiting time much shorter.  An 'easy' report makes it quite a bit longer.

Now, if the student gets the next viewing wrong, we want to count it as a failure.  If the student gets it right (regardless of the difficulty the student reports), we count it as a success.

I want to maximize the utility function $\frac{|\text{success}|}{|\text{total}|}$ by varying the 5-tuple.  I guess $\frac{|\text{success}|}{|\text{failure}|}$ would serve the same purpose.

Comment: This isn't really clear. Can you state your situation in simple English w/ a concrete example? What is your response variable? Is it a count of success & failures, or a utility? How is the experiment set up?

Comment: I gather your experiment will be *adaptive*, the nature of the next problem that a student tries will be dependent on the set of problems the student has not yet done, or done correctly, & for those that were missed before: how long it has been since they tried & how easy they thought it was. What you are trying to figure out here is how to program the experiment with respect to how long / how many intervening problems the student should see before you show then the same problem again. Is that correct?

Comment: @gung: Yes, that's right.  But the dependency of the next problem on the "current" one is weak.  New problems are randomly drawn from a bank.  The next one seen is only dependent because it might have been seen and scheduled already.